# Rendering the number 10,958 with the string 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Brazilian mathematician Inder Taneja has found a way of expressing every number between 1 and 11,111, except 10,958, by inserting mathematical operators in between the numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and evaluating the expression. He did so using the four basic arithmetic operations, exponentiation, concatenation, and brackets, but avoiding factorials, square roots, and decimals. If these last three operations are allowed, can 10,958 be likewise expressed?

Comment: Do the digits 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 have to be in order?

Comment: Yes, they have to be in order.

Comment: Link to Taneja's paper for those who are interested in all the other numbers: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1479v5.pdf

Comment: This is a "decreasing" solution: 9 8 7.... 1 rather than increasing.

Comment: @Bernardi Yes, I deleted my comment when I saw it

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Taking from

> $(1 + 2 + 34) \times (5 × 6 + 7) \times 8 + 9 = 10961$

We have

> $(1 + 2 + 34) \times (5 × 6 + 7) \times 8 + (\sqrt{9})! = 10958$

Comment: Ha! I hadn't even thought of looking at the other solutions and finding one I could tweak! Here I was racking my brain from scratch! :) Nice one! +1

Comment: +1 for the attempt. But don't you need to have an operator in between each number i.e  you are using 34 directly?

Comment: Going by the OP, concatenation is allowed.

Comment: The solution uses both square roots *and* factorials, so it's not quite in the spirit of the paper.

Answer (score 28):

Voila! With arithmetic operators, factorial and exponents:

> $\mathbf{{(1+2^3)}^4 + 5 - 6! + 7! + (8 \times 9 )}  = {(1+8)}^4 + 5 - 720 + 5040 + 72 = 6561 + 4397 = 10958$

Comment: A great answer using no square roots and concatenation. Good Job.

Comment: The brackets around $(8 \times 9)$ are totally unecessary.

Answer (score 6):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

This is as close as I can get:

> (**1**+**2**)<sup>**3**+**4**</sup> * **5** + (**6** * **7**) - **8** - **9** = **10960**.

Maybe this will give someone an idea of how to get there!

Answer (score 5):

Matt Parker from the Numberphile YouTube channel found a solution and explains it in this [video](https://youtu.be/pasyRUj7UwM).

`||` stands for concatenation. (ie: `1||0 x 2 = 20`)

> 1 x 23 + ((4x5x6)||7 + 8) x 9

Concatenation is heavily used in the paper but I don't think it ever have been used that way. (ie:`(2 x 3) || 2 = 62`)

Does it's stand with the spirit of the paper? It's debatable.

Answer (score 4):

Concatenation is ||

> 1 x 23 + ((4x5x6)||7 + 8) x 9

Comment: This checks out. QUESTION: Am I misreading the OP or does this solution satisfy the Taneja requirements __without__ adding extra operators? since concatenation was allowed to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get

$(12*3*4÷5*6*7+8)*9=10958.4$